# How do I find the Least Common multiple between these

Tags: least-common-multiple

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $x-a,x,$ and $x+a$ are prime polynomials.

Comment: Do you understand what a lcm is?

Comment: Yes, I can find it with integers but with statements like this I do not know how to work...

Comment: It is the same idea. Given two polynomials $p,q$, the polynomial $r$ is the lcm if (1) it is a multiple of $p$ and a multiple of $q$, and (2) any polynomial satisfying (1) is a multiple of $r$. So in this case that makes $r$ obvious.

Answer (score 0):

lcm CAN BE thought in polynomials as you have to give that polynomial which would when divided by these numbers gives a polynomial as it happens for integers.

So thinking along that line a  polynomial I would come across that suffice this condition is

{x+a}x{x-a}

Now I can go to it by just seeing a particular pattern as it happens while dealing with LCM in arithmetic

It will be first take out the factors of each polynomial .

Now take the highest power of each factor that are present in all the polynomials

Here, you see the first polynomial and divide into its factors x+a and x-a now see are these factors available elsewhere and select the highest power of that factor.

Why this magic work?

try to think , If unable comment.